# Calculate Threaded Pipe Lengths and Component Counts to Build Plumbing System

Tags: vba, excel

How can I make this code more efficient?

The purpose of the code is to receive input from the user and then calculate threaded pipe segments and components that are required to build the system.

As you can see, it takes me a large number of lines and identical loops to accomplish this. How can I make the code shorter/more efficient?

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Sub ThreadedPipeCalc()

Dim desLength As Single, end1 As String, end2 As String
Dim none As Single, CS_Con As Single, CS_Un As Single
Dim CS_90deg As Double, CS_Tee As Single, CS_Flange As Single
Dim CS_Con_ct As Integer, CS_Un_ct As Integer, CS_Flange_ct As Integer
Dim CS_90deg_ct As Integer, CS_Tee_ct As Integer
Dim CS_Con_ct_tot As Integer, CS_Un_ct_tot As Integer
Dim CS_90deg_ct_tot As Integer, CS_Tee_ct_tot As Integer
Dim A_pipe As Single, B_pipe As Single, C_pipe As Single
Dim D_pipe As Single, E_pipe As Single, F_pipe As Single
Dim H_pipe As Single, I_pipe As Single, J_pipe As Single
Dim K_pipe As Single, L_pipe As Single, M_pipe As Single
Dim N_pipe As Single, O_pipe As Single, P_pipe As Single
Dim Q_pipe As Single, R_pipe As Single, S_pipe As Single
Dim T_pipe As Single, U_pipe As Single, V_pipe As Single
Dim W_pipe As Single, X_pipe As Single, Y_pipe As Single
Dim Z_pipe As Single, Threadin As Single, FULLY_pipe As Single
Dim A_ct As Integer, B_ct As Integer, C_ct As Integer
Dim D_ct As Integer, E_ct As Integer, F_ct As Integer
Dim H_ct As Integer, I_ct As Integer, J_ct As Integer
Dim K_ct As Integer, L_ct As Integer, M_ct As Integer
Dim N_ct As Integer, O_ct As Integer, P_ct As Integer
Dim Q_ct As Integer, R_ct As Integer, S_ct As Integer
Dim T_ct As Integer, U_ct As Integer, V_ct As Integer
Dim W_ct As Integer, X_ct As Integer, Y_ct As Integer
Dim Z_ct As Integer, FULLY_ct As Integer
Dim A_ct_tot As Integer, B_ct_tot As Integer, C_ct_tot As Integer
Dim D_ct_tot As Integer, E_ct_tot As Integer, F_ct_tot As Integer
Dim H_ct_tot As Integer, I_ct_tot As Integer, J_ct_tot As Integer
Dim K_ct_tot As Integer, L_ct_tot As Integer, M_ct_tot As Integer
Dim N_ct_tot As Integer, O_ct_tot As Integer, P_ct_tot As Integer
Dim Q_ct_tot As Integer, R_ct_tot As Integer, S_ct_tot As Integer
Dim T_ct_tot As Integer, U_ct_tot As Integer, V_ct_tot As Integer
Dim W_ct_tot As Integer, X_ct_tot As Integer, Y_ct_tot As Integer
Dim Z_ct_tot As Integer, FULLY_ct_tot As Integer
Dim segCount As Integer
Dim CountRedux As Boolean, continue As Integer

continue = 6
none = 0
CS_Con = 2.53
SS_Con = 2.5
CS_Un = 3
SS_Un = 2.85
CS_90deg = 2.25
SS_90deg = 2.28
CS_Tee = 2.25
SS_Tee = 2.26
CS_Flange = 1
SS_Flange = 1
SS_Flang_red = 1.1875
SS_Cap = 1.77
Threadin = 0.563

A_pipe = 126
B_pipe = 72
C_pipe = 60
D_pipe = 48
E_pipe = 36
F_pipe = 24
G_pipe = 22
H_pipe = 20
I_pipe = 18
J_pipe = 16
K_pipe = 14
L_pipe = 12
M_pipe = 11
N_pipe = 10
O_pipe = 9
P_pipe = 8
Q_pipe = 7
R_pipe = 6.5
S_pipe = 6
T_pipe = 5.5
U_pipe = 5
V_pipe = 4.5
W_pipe = 4
X_pipe = 3.5
Y_pipe = 3
Z_pipe = 2.5
FULLY_pipe = 2

While continue = 6

segCount = 0
Range("C3:C32").Value = 0
CS_Con_ct = 0
CS_Un_ct = 0
CS_90deg_ct = 0
CS_Tee_ct = 0
CS_Flange_ct = 0
A_ct = 0
B_ct = 0
C_ct = 0
D_ct = 0
E_ct = 0
F_ct = 0
G_ct = 0
H_ct = 0
I_ct = 0
J_ct = 0
K_ct = 0
L_ct = 0
M_ct = 0
N_ct = 0
O_ct = 0
P_ct = 0
Q_ct = 0
R_ct = 0
S_ct = 0
T_ct = 0
U_ct = 0
V_ct = 0
W_ct = 0
X_ct = 0
Y_ct = 0
Z_ct = 0
FULLY_ct = 0

CS_Con_ct_tot = Range("D3")
CS_Un_ct_tot = Range("D4")
CS_90deg_ct_tot = Range("D5")
CS_Tee_ct_tot = Range("D6")
A_ct_tot = Range("D7")
B_ct_tot = Range("D8")
C_ct_tot = Range("D9")
D_ct_tot = Range("D10")
E_ct_tot = Range("D11")
F_ct_tot = Range("D12")
G_ct_tot = Range("D13")
H_ct_tot = Range("D14")
I_ct_tot = Range("D15")
J_ct_tot = Range("D16")
K_ct_tot = Range("D17")
L_ct_tot = Range("D18")
M_ct_tot = Range("D19")
N_ct_tot = Range("D20")
O_ct_tot = Range("D21")
P_ct_tot = Range("D22")
Q_ct_tot = Range("D23")
R_ct_tot = Range("D24")
S_ct_tot = Range("D25")
T_ct_tot = Range("D26")
U_ct_tot = Range("D27")
V_ct_tot = Range("D28")
W_ct_tot = Range("D29")
X_ct_tot = Range("D30")
Y_ct_tot = Range("D31")
Z_ct_tot = Range("D32")
FULLY_ct_tot = Range("D33")

desLength = Application.InputBox("Enter the desired end to center or center to center length", Type:=1)
end1 = Application.InputBox("Enter End1 Connection (none, Connector, Union, 90deg, or Tee)", Type:=2)
If end1 = Range("A1") Then
    CountRedux = True
Else
    CountRedux = False
End If
end2 = Application.InputBox("Enter End2 Connection (none, Connector, Union, 90deg, or Tee)", Type:=2)

Range("A1") = end2
Range("B2") = desLength

If end1 = "Connector" Then
    CS_Con_ct = CS_Con_ct + 1
    If CountRedux = False Then CS_Con_ct_tot = CS_Con_ct_tot + 1
    desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin
End If
If end1 = "Union" Then
    CS_Un_ct = CS_Un_ct + 1
    If CountRedux = False Then CS_Un_ct_tot = CS_Un_ct_tot + 1
    desLength = desLength - CS_Un + Threadin
End If
If end1 = "90deg" Then
    CS_90deg_ct = CS_90deg_ct + 1
    If CountRedux = False Then CS_90deg_ct_tot = CS_90deg_ct_tot + 1
    desLength = desLength - CS_90deg + Threadin
End If
If end1 = "Tee" Then
    CS_Tee_ct = CS_Tee_ct + 1
    If CountRedux = False Then CS_Tee_ct_tot = CS_Tee_ct_tot + 1
    desLength = desLength - CS_Tee + Threadin
End If
If end2 = "Connector" Then
    CS_Con_ct = CS_Con_ct + 1
    CS_Con_ct_tot = CS_Con_ct_tot + 1
    desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin
End If
If end2 = "Union" Then
    CS_Un_ct = CS_Un_ct + 1
    CS_Un_ct_tot = CS_Un_ct_tot + 1
    desLength = desLength - CS_Un + Threadin
End If
If end2 = "90deg" Then
    CS_90deg_ct = CS_90deg_ct + 1
    CS_90deg_ct_tot = CS_90deg_ct_tot + 1
    desLength = desLength - CS_90deg + Threadin
End If
If end2 = "Tee" Then
    CS_Tee_ct = CS_Tee_ct + 1
    CS_Tee_ct_tot = CS_Tee_ct_tot + 1
    desLength = desLength - CS_Tee + Threadin
End If

'While desLength >= A_pipe
'    A_ct = A_ct + 1
'    segCount = segCount + 1
'    desLength = desLength - A_pipe
'    If segCount > 2 Then
'        desLength = desLength + CS_Con - Threadin - Threadin
'    End If
'Wend
While desLength >= B_pipe
    B_ct = B_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - B_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= C_pipe
    C_ct = C_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - C_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= D_pipe
    D_ct = D_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - D_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= E_pipe
    E_ct = E_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - E_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= F_pipe
    F_ct = F_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - F_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= G_pipe
    G_ct = G_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - G_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= H_pipe
    H_ct = H_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - H_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= I_pipe
    I_ct = I_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - I_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= J_pipe
    J_ct = J_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - J_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= K_pipe
    K_ct = K_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - K_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= L_pipe
    L_ct = L_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - L_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= M_pipe
    M_ct = M_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - M_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= N_pipe
    N_ct = N_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - N_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= O_pipe
    O_ct = O_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - O_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= P_pipe
    P_ct = P_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - P_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= Q_pipe
    Q_ct = Q_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - Q_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= R_pipe
    R_ct = R_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - R_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= S_pipe
    S_ct = S_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - S_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= T_pipe
    T_ct = T_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - T_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= U_pipe
    U_ct = U_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - U_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= V_pipe
    V_ct = V_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - V_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= W_pipe
    W_ct = W_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - W_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= X_pipe
    X_ct = X_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - X_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= Y_pipe
    Y_ct = Y_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - Y_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength >= Z_pipe
    Z_ct = Z_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - Z_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend
While desLength > 0
    FULLY_ct = FULLY_ct + 1
    segCount = segCount + 1
    desLength = desLength - FULLY_pipe
    If segCount >= 2 Then
        desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin
    End If
Wend

CS_Con_ct_p = segCount - 1
CS_Con_ct_tot = CS_Con_ct_tot + CS_Con_ct_p

A_ct_tot = A_ct + A_ct_tot
B_ct_tot = B_ct + B_ct_tot
C_ct_tot = C_ct + C_ct_tot
D_ct_tot = D_ct + D_ct_tot
E_ct_tot = E_ct + E_ct_tot
F_ct_tot = F_ct + F_ct_tot
G_ct_tot = G_ct + G_ct_tot
H_ct_tot = H_ct + H_ct_tot
I_ct_tot = I_ct + I_ct_tot
J_ct_tot = J_ct + J_ct_tot
K_ct_tot = K_ct + K_ct_tot
L_ct_tot = L_ct + L_ct_tot
M_ct_tot = M_ct + M_ct_tot
N_ct_tot = N_ct + N_ct_tot
O_ct_tot = O_ct + O_ct_tot
P_ct_tot = P_ct + P_ct_tot
Q_ct_tot = Q_ct + Q_ct_tot
R_ct_tot = R_ct + R_ct_tot
S_ct_tot = S_ct + S_ct_tot
T_ct_tot = T_ct + T_ct_tot
U_ct_tot = U_ct + U_ct_tot
V_ct_tot = V_ct + V_ct_tot
W_ct_tot = W_ct + W_ct_tot
X_ct_tot = X_ct + X_ct_tot
Y_ct_tot = Y_ct + Y_ct_tot
Z_ct_tot = Z_ct + Z_ct_tot
FULLY_ct_tot = FULLY_ct + FULLY_ct_tot

Range("C3") = CS_Con_ct
Range("C4") = CS_Un_ct
Range("C5") = CS_90deg_ct
Range("C6") = CS_Tee_ct
Range("C7") = A_ct
Range("C8") = B_ct
Range("C9") = C_ct
Range("C10") = D_ct
Range("C11") = E_ct
Range("C12") = F_ct
Range("C13") = G_ct
Range("C14") = H_ct
Range("C15") = I_ct
Range("C16") = J_ct
Range("C17") = K_ct
Range("C18") = L_ct
Range("C19") = M_ct
Range("C20") = N_ct
Range("C21") = O_ct
Range("C22") = P_ct
Range("C23") = Q_ct
Range("C24") = R_ct
Range("C25") = S_ct
Range("C26") = T_ct
Range("C27") = U_ct
Range("C28") = V_ct
Range("C29") = W_ct
Range("C30") = X_ct
Range("C31") = Y_ct
Range("C32") = Z_ct
Range("C33") = FULLY_ct

Range("D3") = CS_Con_ct_tot
Range("D4") = CS_Un_ct_tot
Range("D5") = CS_90deg_ct_tot
Range("D6") = CS_Tee_ct_tot
Range("D7") = A_ct_tot
Range("D8") = B_ct_tot
Range("D9") = C_ct_tot
Range("D10") = D_ct_tot
Range("D11") = E_ct_tot
Range("D12") = F_ct_tot
Range("D13") = G_ct_tot
Range("D14") = H_ct_tot
Range("D15") = I_ct_tot
Range("D16") = J_ct_tot
Range("D17") = K_ct_tot
Range("D18") = L_ct_tot
Range("D19") = M_ct_tot
Range("D20") = N_ct_tot
Range("D21") = O_ct_tot
Range("D22") = P_ct_tot
Range("D23") = Q_ct_tot
Range("D24") = R_ct_tot
Range("D25") = S_ct_tot
Range("D26") = T_ct_tot
Range("D27") = U_ct_tot
Range("D28") = V_ct_tot
Range("D29") = W_ct_tot
Range("D30") = X_ct_tot
Range("D31") = Y_ct_tot
Range("D32") = Z_ct_tot
Range("D33") = FULLY_ct_tot

continue = MsgBox("Do you have another segment?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
Wend

Call PresentThreadedCalc

End Sub
```

[image]

As you can see, I as the pipe continues to decrease in length (as segments are used to equal the total length) I continually check to see which shorter length now needs to be used.

However, there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: To be on-topic, you'll need to provide the complete procedure. As it is, we have no idea what `B_pipe`, or `O_pipe`, etc are.

Comment: Full code is now attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of *all* code modules. Without it, a typo will create a whole new variable, potentially leading to unexpected and difficult to locate bugs.

   1. `SS_Con` is not defined.
   2. `SS_Un` is not defined
   3. etc...
2. There's no need to initialize variables to "empty" (numerics to zero, strings to "" or `vbNull`) VBA will do that for you by default.
3. Fully qualify *all* workbook/worksheet references. `Range("")` references implicitly refer to the currently active worksheet, and that can lead to unintended errors.
4. `Continue = 6` was very confusing. Eliminate "magic numbers" by using built in VBA enumerations. `Continue = vbYes` is much more explicit.
5. Extract all the repetitive code into `Sub`s or `Fuction`s. To do so requires that you change the way you're storing all that repetitive data. Many variations on the same variable screams for an array.
6. You may want to consider defined named ranges for the input/output fields, then referencing those in your code. That way if someone happens to insert a row or column, or moves a cell somewhere, your code will happily follow right along.
7. `Call` is a deprecated function, and there's no need to use it. Just put in the name of the `Sub` or `Function` and VBA will happily execute the routine.

Instead of trying to describe all the changes, I wrote it up:

```
Option Explicit

Enum ConnecterTypes
  Connector
  Union
  Elbow90
  Tee
  Flange
End Enum
Private Const ConnectorTypeCount = 5

Enum PipeLengths
  A
  B
  C
  D
  E
  F
  G
  H
  I
  J
  K
  L
  M
  N
  O
  P
  Q
  R
  S
  T
  U
  V
  W
  X
  Y
  Z
  Fully
End Enum
Private Const PipeTypeCount = 27                 'must match number of enumes in PipeLengths

Private Const CS_Con As Double = 2.53
Private Const SS_Con As Double = 2.5
Private Const CS_Un As Double = 3
Private Const SS_Un As Double = 2.85
Private Const CS_90deg As Double = 2.25
Private Const SS_90deg As Double = 2.28
Private Const CS_Tee As Double = 2.25
Private Const SS_Tee As Double = 2.26
Private Const CS_Flange As Double = 1
Private Const SS_Flange As Double = 1
Private Const SS_Flang_red As Double = 1.1875
Private Const SS_Cap As Double = 1.77
Private Const Threadin As Double = 0.563

Sub ThreadedPipeCalc()

  Dim PipeCount(PipeTypeCount) As Long
  Dim StandardPipeLengths(PipeTypeCount) As Single
  InitializeStandardPipeLengths StandardPipeLengths

  Dim continue As Integer
  continue = vbYes

  While continue = vbYes
    Dim ConnectorCountTotal(ConnectorTypeCount) As Long
    InitializeConnectorTotalCounts ConnectorCountTotal
    Dim PipeCountTotal(PipeTypeCount) As Long
    InitializePipeTotalCounts PipeCountTotal

    Dim desLength As Single
    desLength = Application.InputBox("Enter the desired end to center or center to center length", Type:=1)

    'NOTE: commented pseudocode is for you to write some validation code to ensure the user is giving you a valid end type
    '      A function called "NotValidEndType" that accepts a string and returns a boolean would be good
    Dim end1  As String
    'While NotValidEndType(End1)
    end1 = Application.InputBox("Enter End1 Connection (none, Connector, Union, 90deg, or Tee)", Type:=2)
    'end while
    Dim end2  As String
    'While NotValidEndType(End2)
    end2 = Application.InputBox("Enter End2 Connection (none, Connector, Union, 90deg, or Tee)", Type:=2)
    'end while

    Dim CountRedux As Boolean
    If end1 = Range("A1") Then
      CountRedux = True
    Else
      CountRedux = False
    End If

    Range("A1") = end2
    Range("B2") = desLength

    Dim ConnectorCount(ConnectorTypeCount) As Long
    CheckEnd end1, CountRedux, ConnectorCount, ConnectorCountTotal, desLength
    CheckEnd end2, CountRedux, ConnectorCount, ConnectorCountTotal, desLength

    Dim segCount As Long
    Dim Looper As Integer
    'NOTE: I run from 0 to PipeTypecount - this includes pipe length "A". If you want to exclude that, change the 0 to 1 vvv
    For Looper = 0 To PipeTypeCount - 1
      PipeCount(Looper) = 0                      'initialize this segment's pipe count in case this isn't our first time through
      GetLenthCount Looper, PipeCount(), desLength, segCount, StandardPipeLengths(Looper)
      ConnectorCount(Connector) = ConnectorCount(Connector) + segCount - 1 'I think this is what you're after - confirm the logic
      PipeCountTotal(Looper) = PipeCountTotal(Looper) + PipeCount(Looper) 'update total pipe count
    Next

    'your original code sets these, but I'm not sure what they're used for - you never reference them elsewhere
    '    CS_Con_ct_p = segCount - 1
    '    CS_Con_ct_tot = CS_Con_ct_tot + CS_Con_ct_p

    ShowConnectorCounts ConnectorCount, "C"
    ShowPipeCounts PipeCount, "C"
    ShowConnectorCounts ConnectorCountTotal, "D"
    ShowPipeCounts PipeCountTotal, "D"

    continue = MsgBox("Do you have another segment?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
  Wend

'  Call PresentThreadedCalc

End Sub

Private Sub InitializeConnectorTotalCounts(ByRef Counts() As Long)

  Dim Looper  As Integer

  'note: no initialization of the "flange" count was found in the initial code, increase the loop count by 1 if you want to init "Flange"
  For Looper = 0 To ConnectorTypeCount - 2
    Counts(Looper) = Range("D" & CStr(Looper + 3))
  Next

End Sub

Private Sub InitializePipeTotalCounts(ByRef Counts() As Long)

  Dim Looper  As Integer

  For Looper = 0 To PipeTypeCount - 1
    Counts(Looper) = Range("D" & CStr(Looper + 7))
  Next

End Sub

Private Sub ShowConnectorCounts(ByRef Counts() As Long, ByVal Col As String)

  Dim Looper  As Integer

  'note: no display of the "flange" count was found in the initial code, increase the loop count by 1 if you want to show "Flange"
  For Looper = 0 To ConnectorTypeCount - 2
    Range(Col & CStr(Looper + 3)) = Counts(Looper)
  Next

End Sub

Private Sub ShowPipeCounts(ByRef Counts() As Long, ByVal Col As String)

  Dim Looper  As Integer

  For Looper = 0 To PipeTypeCount - 1
    Range(Col & CStr(Looper + 7)) = Counts(Looper)
  Next

End Sub

Private Sub InitializeStandardPipeLengths(ByRef Pipes() As Single)

  Pipes(A) = 126
  Pipes(B) = 72
  Pipes(C) = 60
  Pipes(D) = 48
  Pipes(E) = 36
  Pipes(F) = 24
  Pipes(G) = 22
  Pipes(H) = 20
  Pipes(I) = 18
  Pipes(J) = 16
  Pipes(K) = 14
  Pipes(L) = 12
  Pipes(M) = 11
  Pipes(N) = 10
  Pipes(O) = 9
  Pipes(P) = 8
  Pipes(Q) = 7
  Pipes(R) = 6.5
  Pipes(S) = 6
  Pipes(T) = 5.5
  Pipes(U) = 5
  Pipes(V) = 4.5
  Pipes(W) = 4
  Pipes(X) = 3.5
  Pipes(Y) = 3
  Pipes(Z) = 2.5
  Pipes(Fully) = 2

End Sub

Private Sub CheckEnd(ByVal TheEnd As String, ByVal Redux As Boolean, ByRef ConCount() As Long, ByRef ConCountTotal() As Long, ByRef desLength As Single)

  If TheEnd = "Connector" Then
    ConCount(Connector) = ConCount(Connector) + 1
    If Not Redux Then
      ConCountTotal(Connector) = ConCountTotal(Connector) + 1
    End If
    desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin
  ElseIf TheEnd = "Union" Then
    ConCount(Union) = ConCount(Union) + 1
    If Not Redux Then
      ConCountTotal(Union) = ConCountTotal(Union) + 1
    End If
    desLength = desLength - CS_Un + Threadin
  ElseIf TheEnd = "90deg" Then
    ConCount(Elbow90) = ConCount(Elbow90) + 1
    If Not Redux Then
      ConCountTotal(Elbow90) = ConCountTotal(Elbow90) + 1
    End If
    desLength = desLength - CS_90deg + Threadin
  ElseIf TheEnd = "Tee" Then
    ConCount(Tee) = ConCount(Tee) + 1
    If Not Redux Then
      ConCountTotal(Tee) = ConCountTotal(Tee) + 1
    End If
    desLength = desLength - CS_Tee + Threadin
  End If

End Sub

Private Sub GetLenthCount(ByVal Pipe As Long, ByRef PipeCount() As Long, ByRef desLength As Single, ByRef segCount As Long, ByVal stdPipeLength As Single)

  While desLength >= stdPipeLength
    PipeCount(Pipe) = PipeCount(Pipe) + 1
    desLength = desLength - stdPipeLength
    segCount = segCount + 1
    If segCount > 2 Then
      desLength = desLength + CS_Con - (Threadin * 2)
    End If
  Wend

End Sub
```

- The `enums` give you workable names to reference elements of the arrays.
- The `Constants` mean you don't have to spend code initializing variables, they're preinitialized and you can't accidentally change them.

  - `Enum PipeLengths` may be a smidge overkill, however, if you ever have to add a new length, whether it's "AA", "A1" or "XYZPDQ", you can add it anywhere you want in the enum, then reference it anywhere you want in `InitializeStandardPipeLengths` and it will "just work".
- `None` was declared and assigned, but it's never used, so I removed it
- It appears that you never initialize or count "Flange" connectors. I included them in the code, but don't initialize them. There's a comment where you need to make the change if that was an oversight.
- Your code allowed the user to enter "Gibberish" as an end fitting type. I'd suggest a data validation routine (as pseudo-coded, above) to ensure that the text the user enters is one of your known, valid types. Loop until it is valid. (You may want to allow for a "Quit" option that immediately exits the code, too, just in case.)
- I left `PresentThreadedCalc` commented at the end - I'm not sure what it does, and, since I didn't have it declared, I couldn't get a clean compile with it in there.

**NOTE:** Code is written & compiles cleanly, *however* there's no guarantee that it will actually execute or that I've duplicated your logic 100%, so *please* make sure all your calculations are still correct, and expect that you may have to do some minor debugging.

Comment: Instead of an arrays and enums combination, I would recommend to use a `Scripting.Dictionary`. This might be a bit less safe but allows to use the names of the ends directly as keys.

Comment: The `CS_*` should also be a collection with the ends as names. That would allow to completely eliminate the elseif blocks.

Comment: A code review of the code review... I'm good with that, @M.Doerner!

Comment: Do you have a reference for how using the dictionary would work? I haven't done that before.

Comment: A handy reference in the [SO Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3667/scripting-dictionary-object#t=201706161856175303559).

Comment: I'm working through implementing all changes and suggestions. What is the purpose of 'enum' and what is its strength? (I looked it up via standard documentation, but Microsoft isn't very helpful...) TIA

Comment: an `Enum` is a an integer value, defaults to starting at 0 and incrementing by 1 (you can assign any values you'd like). Gives a handy way of using "named" numbers without `CONST` or `Dim` everywhere - in particular for the `ConnectorTypes` `enum`, since we really don't care what the number is, we just want a handy way to know that to get the Elbow90 count we use `ConnectorCountTotal(Elbow90)` and it doesn't matter where in the array it is actually stored. If you ever need an Elbow45, just add it to the enum, increment `ConnectorTypeCount` by 1 and away you go!

Comment: You could use an `enum` for your pipe lengths, as well, _except_ that your pipes come in fractional inch lengths. If you got rid of those pesky R, T, V, X & Z pipes, it would work just fine with `Enum PipeLengths` : `A = 126` : `B = 72`, etc. Then, in `GetLenthCount` you could do `desLength = desLength - pipe` and not need to pass in `stdPipeLength` as a param. But, alas, you cannot do this in your particular implementation because of the fractional values.

Comment: Well... almost on using the `enum` for `PipeLengths`. Your array reference of `PipeLengths(A)` would be equivalent to `PipeLengths(126)`, so you'd need to `Dim` the array appropriately, but otherwise, it would work.

Comment: You got me thinking about this again... in `Sub GetLengthCount()`, there is this line: `desLength = desLength + CS_Con - (Threadin * 2)`. It's **adding** the length of `CS_Con` to the desired length. Your original line is `desLength = desLength - CS_Con + Threadin + Threadin` which is adding the `Threadin` twice. Based on my understanding of plumbing (nothing's leaked in my house as yet! :) I'm not certain that either of these is correct, however you're the expert. Be certain you double check that line and ensure the proper math is happening there.

Comment: @Freeman take a look at what I've posted as an answer and let me know what you think

Comment: @M.Doerner I've attempted to implement dictionaries like you suggested.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for the additional comments. If my logic isn't clearer in my new answer, then I'll explain the pipe logic more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I continued working on this code based on @Freeman's answer and ended up with this. (It's declared explicit at the top of the module.)

```
Sub ThreadedPipeCalcNEW()
    On Error Resume Next

    ResetThreadedCalc

    'above line needed for input validation
    'dimension variables and set constants
    Dim j As Variant, k As Variant, dictCon As Object, dictPipe As Object
    Dim desLength As Single, desiredLength As Single, end1 As String, end2 As String
    Dim matTypes As Variant, myMaterial As String
    Dim continue As Integer, whileCount As Integer, conLooper As Integer, pipLooper As Integer
    Dim cell As Variant, lastRow As Variant
    Const Threadin = 0.563 'this is how far a pipe threads into a fitting (9/16 of an inch)

    'initialize continue so that main while loop begins properly
    continue = vbYes
    'initialize material types
    matTypes = Array("carbon", "stainless")
    'initialize dictionaries
    Set dictCon = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictPipe = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictCon.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'non-case-sensitive comparison
    dictPipe.CompareMode = vbTextCompare 'non-case-sensitive comparison

    'populate connector dictionary
    dictCon.Add Key:="carbonConnector", Item:=2.53
    dictCon.Add Key:="carbonUnion", Item:=3
    dictCon.Add Key:="carbon90Deg", Item:=2.25
    dictCon.Add Key:="carbon45Deg", Item:=0
    dictCon.Add Key:="carbonTee", Item:=2.25
    dictCon.Add Key:="carbonFlange", Item:=1
    dictCon.Add Key:="stainlessConnector", Item:=2.5
    dictCon.Add Key:="stainlessUnion", Item:=2.85
    dictCon.Add Key:="stainless90Deg", Item:=2.28
    dictCon.Add Key:="stainless45Deg", Item:=0
    dictCon.Add Key:="stainlessTee", Item:=2.26
    dictCon.Add Key:="stainlessFlange", Item:=1
    dictCon.Add Key:="stainlessReducingflange", Item:=1.1875
    dictCon.Add Key:="none", Item:=0

    'populate pipe dictionary
    dictPipe.Add Key:="A_pipe", Item:=72
    dictPipe.Add Key:="B_pipe", Item:=60
    dictPipe.Add Key:="C_pipe", Item:=48
    dictPipe.Add Key:="D_pipe", Item:=36
    dictPipe.Add Key:="E_pipe", Item:=30
    dictPipe.Add Key:="F_pipe", Item:=24
    dictPipe.Add Key:="G_pipe", Item:=18
    dictPipe.Add Key:="H_pipe", Item:=12
    dictPipe.Add Key:="I_pipe", Item:=11
    dictPipe.Add Key:="J_pipe", Item:=10
    dictPipe.Add Key:="K_pipe", Item:=9
    dictPipe.Add Key:="L_pipe", Item:=8
    dictPipe.Add Key:="M_pipe", Item:=7
    dictPipe.Add Key:="N_pipe", Item:=6
    dictPipe.Add Key:="O_pipe", Item:=5.5
    dictPipe.Add Key:="P_pipe", Item:=5
    dictPipe.Add Key:="Q_pipe", Item:=4.5
    dictPipe.Add Key:="R_pipe", Item:=4
    dictPipe.Add Key:="S_pipe", Item:=3.5
    dictPipe.Add Key:="T_pipe", Item:=3
    dictPipe.Add Key:="U_pipe", Item:=2.5
    dictPipe.Add Key:="FULLY_pipe", Item:=0 'really a fully threaded pipe nipple is two inches, but it needs to be used whenever there is a remainder distance

    'allows user to input material type for whole system
    While IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Trim(myMaterial), matTypes, 0))
        myMaterial = Application.InputBox("Enter Material (carbon or stainless)", Type:=2)
        If myMaterial = "False" Then Exit Sub 'user clicked cancel,so exit program
        myMaterial = Trim(myMaterial)
    Wend

    'begin while loop to accept user input and run calculations
    While continue = vbYes
        'on second loop end1 will be assigned as the old end2
        end1 = end2
        'end2 will be reset to blank so that it is again set by user input
        end2 = ""

        'initialize for loop component and pipe counters
        'this allows the proper cell tallies to be added
        conLooper = 2 'set this to the connector row
        pipLooper = 16 'set this to the first row of pipe

        'allows user to input connection types while checking for errors
        'and ending the program if cancel button is pressed
        While IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Trim(end1), dictCon.Keys, 0))
            end1 = Application.InputBox("Enter End1 Connection" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "(none, connector, union, 90deg, 45deg, tee, flange, or reducingflange).", Type:=2)
            If end1 = "False" Then Exit Sub 'user clicked cancel,so exit program
            If end1 <> "none" Then
                end1 = Application.Proper(end1)
                end1 = myMaterial & end1
            End If
        Wend

        'accepts user input for length of segment center/end to center/end
        desiredLength = Application.InputBox("Enter the desired end to center or center to center length in INCHES." _
                                        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The previous length was " & CStr(desiredLength) & ".", Type:=1)
        desLength = desiredLength 'passes input to a dynamic number for rest of program
                                  'this way, the previously entered length can be shown when loop run more than once

        'allows user to input connection types while checking for errors
        'and ending the program if cancel button is pressed
        While IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Trim(end2), dictCon.Keys, 0))
            end2 = Application.InputBox("Enter End2 Connection" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "(none, connector, union, 90deg, 45deg, tee, flange, or reducingflange)." _
            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The previous end was " & end1 & ".", Type:=2)
            If end2 = "False" Then Exit Sub 'user clicked cancel,so exit program
            If end2 <> "none" Then
                end2 = Application.Proper(end2)
                end2 = myMaterial & end2
            End If
        Wend

        'iterate through keys, check ends, add to counts, and alter desLength (aka desiredLength) by connector dimensions (accounting for threadin)
        For Each j In dictCon.Keys
            If end1 = j And whileCount = 0 Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(conLooper)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(conLooper)).Value + 1
                desLength = desLength - dictCon.Item(j) + Threadin
            End If
            If end1 = j And whileCount > 0 Then 'do not add to the component count if the end has been accounted for as end1/end2 already
                desLength = desLength - dictCon.Item(j) + Threadin
            End If
            If end2 = j Then 'second end is always considered new and is thus added to the count
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(conLooper)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(conLooper)).Value + 1
                desLength = desLength - dictCon.Item(j) + Threadin
            End If
            conLooper = conLooper + 1
        Next j

        'iterate through keys, handle fully threaded pipe specially, otherwise add pipe and modfify desiredLength according to pipe length
        'account for the addition of connectors when more than one pipe piece is used from one connector to another
        For Each k In dictPipe.Keys
            While desLength - 1.404 >= dictPipe.Item(k)
                If k = "FULLY_pipe" Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(pipLooper)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(pipLooper)).Value + 1
                    desLength = desLength - 2
                Else
                    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(pipLooper)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(pipLooper)).Value + 1
                    desLength = desLength - dictPipe.Item(k)
                    If desLength <> 0 Then
                        If myMaterial = "carbon" Then
                            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value + 1 'hardcoded position of connector row
                        Else
                            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8").Value + 1 'hardcoded position of connector row
                        End If
                        desLength = desLength - dictCon.Item(myMaterial & "Connector") + (2 * Threadin)
                    End If
                End If
            Wend
            pipLooper = pipLooper + 1
        Next k

        'if there is any remaining pipe length, take care of it with a fully threaded piece; this ensures the pipe is always slightly too long instead of too short
        If desLength > 0 And desLength <= 1.404 Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(pipLooper - 1)).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & CStr(pipLooper - 1)).Value + 1
        End If

        'run again until user has no more segments
        'this allows the program to build out a whole BOM
        continue = MsgBox("Do you have another segment?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

        'add one to the loop count, indicating if the connector count
        'must be modified since end1 is being assigned as the previous end2
        whileCount = whileCount + 1
    Wend

    'find used range; ensures code is easier to edit
    lastRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'hide rows with unneeded components
    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & CStr(lastRow)).Cells
        If cell.Value = 0 Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next

End Sub
```

The reset subfunction is as follows

```
Sub ResetThreadedCalc()

    Dim cell2 As Variant, lastRow2 As Variant

    'find used range; ensures code is easier to edit
    lastRow2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'unhide rows or set values to zero
    For Each cell2 In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & CStr(lastRow2)).Cells
        If cell2.Value = 0 Then
            cell2.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            cell2.Value = 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

And the sheet was modified to be

[image: Sheet interface]

Please let me know your thoughts on if this can be made any better! I'm happy to continue improving.

As always, thanks for all your help, suggestions, and time.

Cheers,
Tanner